Systematic king's overthrown culture
How can a society thrive if it's monarchical apparatus is based on a systematic overthrown of their king by a stronger claimant? Would any society withstand such political instability? How? As stated above, it would need not only to survive, but thrive to a point of becoming a feared military power.

The king will naturally try to consolidate his own control and not be overthrown. If he manages to survive until his death or retirement, then he has to pass the throne on to someone - be that his son or someone else. If that son doesn't manage to hold onto power, then one of his generals will overthrow him. Well, now you've got the Roman Empire, which did OK as a military power. If you the king to always be replaced by a coup rather than succession - how can you even make that work? What guarantees that someone will be able to overthrow him?

As @AlexP said, it is not clear what you are proposing. History shows us that, no matter how "lawful" the current ruler is, if there is an opposition strong enough a convenient justification will be found for overthrowing him. By that standard, all of the hierarchical societies in earth are based to some extent on the systemic overthrow of the leader (specially in democratic societies).

It will thrive until you have nearly equal strength claimants. Then you have civil war which the Romans had ever so often.

While it's true there are historical precedents that demonstrate how civilizations can overcome the the overthrow of a monarch - this isn't a worldbuilding question. There isn't a world rule that would guarantee that any civilization would survive the overthrow of its government. This is a storybuilding question that would have been better asked on [history.se] (as in, "are there historical precedents of a society surviving the overthrow of its monarch?").

the outcome of such system is that the "king" would become less and less important, and the stable administration below him would de facto rule the kingdom. If kings constantly change, then the most powerful person who persists between coronations is the actual ruler. This is likely to be the High Priest, or the Chancellor, or whoever presides over the council of nobles.

You've Described The Roman Empire
During Imperial Rome (31 BC – AD 476) there were about thirty Emperors overthrown by rebellion and an additional 105 cases of other various forms of usurpation. Rome as an Empire was split in halves and quarters and reunified multiple times as Emperors vied for supreme power.
Despite all of this Rome, remained the dominant military power in Europe despite about 500 years of constant in fighting which is over 3 times as long as the average nation survives.
There are 2 keys to the success of the Roman Empire

Put a rugged bureaucracy under the monarch. Rome could endure the constant fighting of Emperors because it was very stable and well managed at the administrative level.  The Emperor was not needed to make sure that trade, taxes, the enforcement of law, and all the other day-to-day operations of the Empire kept going on.  So as long your local magistrates are not also constantly locked into this system of usurpation, then the nation can remain mostly stable regardless of who the head of state is.

Wait until the Empire is established before this system of usurpation begins.  It is hard for a nation to grow when embroiled in internal conflict, but if you start off with a stable hereditary monarchy or republic, you can have your nation first establish itself. Then it only takes one usurper like Julius Caesar to completely change the way the government functions and to kickstart your strongman government at a large scale.



This is the answer. The bureaucratic foundation is the key. In fact, there's one such organization in my story, but I couldn't figure out the entire scope of its functions. Now I know. Thank you. By the way, could you recommend me any bibliography focused on that period of Rome?

@Josué There are so many works written on Ancient Rome, I would not even know where to start.  But you will specifically want to look for things on the Triumvirate Period to learn about how Roman Republic became an Empire, and the Pax Romana to learn how the Empire quickly descended from a very successful meritocracy into a brutal and constant state of internal conflict.

Dont forget the loyalties that are constantly flipping make a culture necessary, were everyone declares the previous emperor insane, evil and deranged.

@Pica A Constitutional mindset is very helpful for this.  When your people are loyal to the law instead of the ruler, it makes accepting a change of leadership much easier.  IE: if your loyalty is to the King instead of King Bob III, then when Lord Rob kills King Bob and becomes the new king, loyalty does not have to shift because it is, as it always was, to "the king".

This ignores the tribalistic nature of people though. Leaders will always demand loyalty. Followers will always demand unity and no dissenters or deserters. To the point were there ever can only be one endeavour executed in parallel. Roman politics was not that different to warlord clan politics in dictatorships in africa. One family leaves another takes over all buisness endavours.

@Nosajimiki You are not wrong. But you goto blend patriotism and constitutionalism. It has to be unpatriotic to be unconstitutional.

@Pica Agreed.  Unpatriotic and unconstitutional also allows for rapid transitions in power, but will threaten the underlying bureaucracy that keeps your nation stable during these takeovers.

China had this with 'The Mandate of Heaven'. A dynasty would rule for a while, then another would rise up and overthrow them. Business as usual.
Chinese actually had a description for it. But almost every Kingdom had much the same thing in practice. You only keep what you can hold and protect. Once you're in, you're appointed by God/s or you wouldn't be there.

There is also the form defines the function that came to full effect in china. Basically, china was conquered several times (once by the mongols), but the new rulers used the bureaucracy and basically became the old rulers with different lineage.

TL;DR: Details matter
Whether or not a monarchical polity, where the head of state is very powerful and is always to be replaced by a stronger contender, can not only survive but flourish and be a great military power depends enormously on the specific setup of its political system. It may be the case that the system is unstable and hinders the development of the realm. It may be the case that the system is stable and helps the development of the realm. Details matter.
For example
The United States of America and France have very strong presidential systems, where the president has more power than any European king, queen, emperor or empress has even had in the last three hundred years. (With the sole exception of His Imperial Majesty Napoleon I, Emperor of the French, but he doesn't really count as he was overthrown after a reign of only ten years.) In practice, the United States of America and France are elective, term-limited, almost absolute monarchies.
And what happens in the United States of America every four years, and in France every five years? The monarch is forced by law and custom to put himself to the test, to see if there is any stronger claimant. And should the monarch prevail, an overthrow is mandated by law and custom at least once every eight years in the United States of America and at least once every ten years in France. (Note that in the case of France this is progress; it used to be that the president-monarch only had to put himself to the test every seven years, and a mandatory overthrow only happened after fourteen years.)
Both the United States of America and France are rich and powerful countries and great military powers.

that being said, while US or France are arguably RULED by a powerful President, the actual CONTROL of the country is in the hands of professional politicians and life-term bureaucrats. it cannot be otherwise, as there would be chaos. Its not about some Deep-State nonsense, but the simple fact that the most important policies and institutions need to persist and be supervised across many presidencies, and elections, not upended randomly every 4 years or so. If say, it takes 16 years to build a highway across the country, then the administration needs to prevent 4 presidents from f-ing it up.

@GoingDurden: It was always like this, even in the most absolutist of the absolutist monarchies. Even when Louis XIV had the impression that the state was him, the reality was it was the bureaucracy who ran the state. As you have said, in a state of any reasonable size it cannot be otherwise.

it is also the matter of information technology. If the best way to distribute your kingly orders is to send dudes on horses around, then you don't really rule anything, so much as occasionally threaten distant people to do your bidding. The local clerks, village elders, nobles and merchants essentially rule their own tiny fiefdoms, because they would die of starvation if they awaited your instructions about how to do their jobs and feed their own. It hardly matters if the king is strong conqueror or a prissy wimp, if he is 700 miles away and irrelevant to the current harvest.

@GoingDurden No deep state?  Don't be absurd.  The term may be new, but scheming bureaucracy, palace intrigue, corrupt officials, is a tale as old as government.  Intrigue and collusion for the (perceived) benefit of the bureaucratic class is arguably the normal historical state of affairs.

@Jedediah, sure! What I meant is that the bureaucratic "Long State" is inevitable, and part of its process is the existence of the "Deep State". The Deep State is not some mysterious conspiracy, just the normal side effect of the Long State, and if you go far enough back in history, the two are the same. Shady rich dudes clinging to power in the shadow of the state is called "Deep State" now, but for most of human history it was just called "Nobility", and was not only expected of them, but necessary to maintain the state itself, because their self-interest was the same as national interest.

@GoingDurden I'm pretty sure remarks about the deep state are specifically calling out intrigue and collusion which isn't in the interests of the nation at large, just the bureaucracy.  Your initial comment was dismissive of that.

@Jedediah, I meant that if you go enough far back in time, intrigue and collusion is indistinguishable from normal workings of the state, because the self-interest of the elite is the same as the interest of the realm. The idea that the state is not the personal property of the elite is relatively new, and relative thin. For example, what we call nepotism today, and show it as an example of the Deep State circumventing the democratic process, was normal state of affairs, not just expected, but necessary.

@GoingDurden I think it's always been the case that people could see daylight between the interests of (the more selfish) elites and the people at large.  And sometimes it may have gone unrecognized but was still true that, say, the Chinese bureaucratic class would be too heavy for the peasants to bear, until a reformer / rebel arose and murdered the emperor, only to be welcomed as the next emperor by the bureaucrats, and if the process didn't winnow the weight of the state incidentally, a new rebellion could hit in the former "reformer's" lifetime.

No ruler worth of their power will rule without fearing and thus guarding themselves from plots against their personas: scheming for replacing the current ruler is a constant in any situation, either via legal or illegal means.
That doesn't prevent the country ruled by the target from prospering, as long as the guide is not affected by corruption and crazy ideas.

"No ruler worth of their power" which is why we've not really had this. I mean, historically "strongest gets to be a leader" has been practised. Just doesn't stick because when a ruler worth their power shows up, they end up to still be a leader even if somebody else is stronger. And sure, even with monarchies there have been coups, overthrows, etc where a stronger leader muscled in to get the throne. It happens but it's not the primary mode of transferring power because most rulers that get the throne don't keep it by sheer might alone.

@VLAZ, the actual power that controls any state is the mundane administration, that by default needs to persist between kings. Kingdoms do not vanish into anarchy when a king is killed, they keep on going. The king that rules the longest, is the one that meshes the best with the existing system, not necessarily the strongest one, because 99% of good rule is getting out of the way of the clerks that actually manage your kingdom. Hence why historically, nations prospered best under "weak" kings, and suffered under badass conquerors who wasted money and time on Alpha Male idiocy.

The king is not that powerful.
The king is the head of the country.  The actual head of state is a lowly functionary.  Kings enjoy power and prestige, and can lead their armies to victory and loot to gain more prestige, but that's for the warrior caste.  The business of maintaining rule of law in the country is the business of the clerks.
Whenever kings get too dangerous or a potential candidate strikes the clerks as a bad choice, the clerks redirect supplies so that they can not get the weapons and rations needed to mount a successful attack.
The clerks try to maintain a creed that it is the duty of the warriors to protect the land.  Sometimes, this even succeeds in persuading them to wage a war that is for the benefit of the land, such as putting down robbers.

Yes, that's pretty much the conclusion. The only difference with respect to my story is that I want those clerks to be committed by law and religious beliefs to every monarch no matter what. They serve the crown, and it doesn't matter on whose head it's resting on.

@Josué that is pretty much how it always worked. Arguably, it cannot work otherwise; a king, even a conqueror who just subjugated the kingdom, cannot just get rid of the clerks, without turning the kingdom into a useless mess. And he cannot supervise all clerks at all times, he would go insane. The king RULES the kingdom, but the senior clerk (chancellor, vizzier, Head Secretary or whatever the are called) actually CONTROLS the kingdom, otherwise nothing would get done. And lets be frank, nobody wants to conquer a kingdom and be king to do petty bureaucracy for 10 hours a day, they delegated.

@GoingDurden  You assume that it always works.  In reality, overthrowing kings causes a lot of confusion, turmoil, and chaos.  It is not unknown for the kingdom to cease to exist as a political entity.  And most kingdoms manage with a lot less bureaucracy than the modern day -- not enough to keep it going on their own.

The doctrine of "Peaceful transition of Power" exists to solve that exact problem. Even for advanced democracies, the election of a new government is a traumatic event. Cabinet members are replaced, people are fired, governing methods change overnight.
The election cycle of modern democracies was invented to manage that problem. To create a peaceful revolution every 4 to 8 years (depending on your country's laws)
So how do you create a lasting government with recurring coups? You indoctrinate the people that the needs of the realm are greater than the pride of the man. That way every ruler would rather give up power, than hurt their country.

Amusingly, the Wakanda Solution (claimant needs to duel the King for the crown) is a relatively sensible solution. No coups, just two dudes duking it out, while the actual administration that runs the country persists.

England returned to the Monarchy after Cromwell
Yes, a kingdom can withstand political instability and the fall of its king and still thrive as a military power.
A historical example or model could be England and  Cromwell, who deposed the British monarchy and formed a short-lived protectorate from 1649 to 1660.
This was a protestant, puritan overthrow of the monarchy by a member of the landed gentry, a small landowner and member of parliament who was 40 years old when he began his military career.   His rank rose during a period of prolonged civil war, when Britain fought with Scotland and Ireland.  Cromwell eventually lead the Parliamentarian army against the Royalist army and defeated Charles I.
Charles I was put on trial and eventually executed.  Why?
"After his succession in 1625, Charles quarrelled with the English Parliament, which sought to curb his royal prerogative. He believed in the divine right of kings, and was determined to govern according to his own conscience. Many of his subjects opposed his policies, in particular the levying of taxes without Parliamentary consent, and perceived his actions as those of a tyrannical absolute monarch. His religious policies, coupled with his marriage to a Roman Catholic, generated antipathy and mistrust from Reformed religious groups such as the English Puritans and Scottish Covenanters, who thought his views too Catholic. He supported high church Anglican ecclesiastics and failed to aid continental Protestant forces successfully during the Thirty Years' War. His attempts to force the Church of Scotland to adopt high Anglican practices led to the Bishops' Wars, strengthened the position of the English and Scottish parliaments, and helped precipitate his own downfall."
-Wikepedia
It appeared one of the matches that lit a powder keg of religious conflicts was attempting to levy a tax by martial law, and dissolving parliament which resisted the tax.
Cromwell established a protectorate and became the Lord Protector of England.  Later Cromwell died of natural causes, and despite an attempt to appoint Cromwell's son, Richard,  as Lord Protector,the royal line returned in the person of Charles II.
"In revenge for his father’s death, Charles II ordered that Oliver Cromwell’s body be dug up the following year. His corpse was hung in chains and flung in a pit, and his severed head was displayed outside Westminster Hall for a couple of decades."
-The Restoration|Royal Museums
While the monarchy returned,the country was moving from a monarchy to a constitutional monarchy where the parliament was gaining importance; the country was able to survive the instability, but it was a time of radical change in the political system as well.
Seems like fertile ground for fictional worldbuilding to me.
If you want to research the life of Cromwell further, you might look at the book and the TV series Wolf Hall.

This is the medieval Middle East as described by Ibn Khaldun! Some mountain or desert tribe overthrows the weak king and moves into the capital. But life in the capital makes them soft and weak, and after two or three generations they are overthrown by another desert or mountain tribe.
However, if the new ruler has enough ambition and charisma (as sometimes happens), they might conquer some neighbouring empires before becoming weak and soft.

Importantly though, while the kings changed a lot, the host of various advisers, viziers chancellors, and courtiers who ran the actual administration persisted between kings, or ever across conquests. It was not rare for the conquerors to just depose the former king but keep the entire bureaucracy intact, which essentially means the bureaucrats ruled.
